# How to get value by class name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In `HTML` below, I want to retrieve the value of the all `<b>` tags using `JavaScript` or `jQuery`

```
<html>
   <head>
</head>
<body>        

 <span id=":zz" class="adl">

                   <b>2</b> 
                   <b>of </b>

                   <b>143 </b>

           </span>

<body>
</html>
```

Can I retrieve all `<b>` tag values using class name in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: what is the desired output format

Comment: `$('.adl b')` to access the values

Comment: @user3141775 Can you correct your span id first?

Comment: this is my auto generated id for this class. so i can't...would u tell me whats is worng in this id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the values in to an array using `$.map()`:

```
var values = $('b').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(values); // = ["2", "of ", "143 "]
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32v8t/)

Comment: Thanks. Was in the process of creating a fiddle ;)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need even need classname to do that.just use:

```
$('.adl b').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
 })
```

Comment: Including `span css class` can match with the question header.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($('span.adl').find('b').text());
```